# How to estimate Pareto shape parameter with bayesian estimation?

Tags: bayesian, pareto-distribution

I want to estimate the shape (alpha) parameter for a Pareto distribution. (We assume that we know the scale parameter =1 ).

The prior is alpha = 2 (and maybe we have always to assume a distribution ? if so, let's say that it is a normal law with mean=2 and sd=0.1).

With we have observations, for example (5,6,9,12,59,4)

Form these data, can we calculate a posterior ?

- maybe we have to give a distribution for likelihood ? Let's say that it is a uniform law
- or in the case of pareto law, we have some typical distribution ?

edit: Xi'an indicated that this question is solved with this question [Conjugated priors (Pareto and Beta), name of the unconditional distribution?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/102922/conjugated-priors-pareto-and-beta-name-of-the-unconditional-distribution), but I can't see how. Could you please give a numerical solution.

```
alpha=rnorm(1000,2,0.1)
obs=c(5,6,9,12,59,4)
#....
post=?
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Conjugated priors (Pareto and Beta), name of the unconditional distribution?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/102922/conjugated-priors-pareto-and-beta-name-of-the-unconditional-distribution)

Comment: @Xi'an Thank you. Could you please give an example of solution for this problem above: I initially we alpha=2, now with observations, how can I compute the new alpha ? (I heard of MCMC...)